# How to get the code to make the user pick between different ranges of random numbers in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, numbers

I want to make a code that generates random numbers from 3 different choices that the user can pick from but the code just doesn't recognize the variable I put to represent those choices. Here is what I've got so far:

```
import random

choose = int(input("1, 2 or 3? "))

if choose == 1:
  num == random.randint(1, 10)
elif choose == 2: 
  num == random.randint(10, 50)
elif choose == 3: 
  num == random.randint(1, 100)
else:
  print("Invalid input")


print(num)
```

Can someone help?

Comment: `==` vs `=` ... makes a difference - try assigning `=` to num instead of comparing `==` it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some confusion. `==` is for **comparison** like `is a equal to b?` and `=` is for assignment. So, just replace to this `num = random.randint(10, 50)`.

Also, you should consider moving `print(num)` inside the `if...elif...else` statements as it can raise an error when invalid input is provided.

```
import random

choose = int(input("1, 2 or 3? "))

if choose == 1:
  num = random.randint(1, 10)
  print("Your Number: "num)
elif choose == 2: 
  num = random.randint(10, 50)
  print("Your Number: "num)
elif choose == 3: 
  num =random.randint(1, 100)
  print("Your Number: "num)
else:
  print("Invalid input")
```